# Where to find MPE Forth Hardware Files?

Tags: embedded, forth

I have two dev kits and I would like to use [MPE Forth](http://www.mpeforth.com/software/forth-cross-compilers/forth-7-cross-compilers/lite-cross-compilers/) Lite on these.

Where can I get hardware (`.ctl` etc.) files for the following:

- [MSP-EXP430FR6989](http://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430FR6989)
- [STM32L053DISCOVERY](http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/32l0538discovery.html)

... or an I use any existing files to get going?

I am a noob and would really like to start with a known working system.

c-:

Comment: I know that the MPE website recommends starting with a known configuration.  I just do not have one at the moment :-(

Comment: It is a bit "niche",  your first approach should be to contact MPE.  It is so niche in fact that there is not even a community support forum as far as I can tell - the tag as 270 followers on SO vs 164k for C.  The world of Forth seems a bit lonely!  I programmed in Forth from MPE on Z80 for a couple of years more that 20 years ago - I wouldn't recommend it!

Comment: How is this on-topic?